# Does Wizards of the Coast still package World Championship Decks?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The most recent decks that I can find are from 2005. Are the top 4 championship decks from each year still being packaged for retail? If so, where's a good place to buy them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately they were discontinued (at around the time you state) for not being widely popular.  The cards could obviously not be played in tournaments and weren't even very good for casual play because of the nonstandard card backs.

A shame because I quite liked the feeling of playing a finely-tuned Pro deck too... but Wizards are just too cagey about printing anything resembling proxies of top-tier tournament cards.

Comment: They were not that popular then, but now they are at least somewhat sought after by cube enthusiasts that appreciate official proxies.